# How can I solve these second order PDE's?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, nonlinear-system, parabolic-pde

I have three PDE's and I tried to solve it through Finite Fourier Transform (FFT) method but could not get the required result. How can I solve it? Is there any other method to solve these equations?

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial\theta_c}{\partial X}-\frac{A_4}{\epsilon(Y^2A_1+YA_2+A_3)\,}\,\frac{\partial^2\theta_c}{\partial Y^2}&=0 \qquad (1) \\
\frac{\partial^2\theta_s}{\partial Y^2}-Bi(\theta_s-\theta_f)&=0 \qquad (2) \\
\kappa\,\frac{\partial^2\theta_f}{\partial Y^2}+Bi(\theta_s-\theta_f)-\kappa\,U_p\,\frac{\partial\theta_f}{\partial X}&=0 \qquad (3)
\end{align*}

Boundary Conditions:

\begin{align*}
\text{at}\quad Y&=0,\qquad \theta_s=\theta_f,\qquad 1=-\kappa\,\frac{\partial\theta_f}{\partial Y}-\frac{\partial\theta_s}{\partial Y}\\
\text{at}\quad Y&=Y_p, \qquad \theta_s=\theta_f=\theta_c,\qquad \gamma=-\frac{\kappa}{\epsilon}\,\frac{\partial\theta_c}{\partial Y}=-\kappa\,\frac{\partial\theta_f}{\partial Y}-\frac{\partial\theta_s}{\partial Y} \\
\text{at}\quad Y&=1,\qquad \frac{\partial\theta_c}{\partial Y}=0 \\
\text{at}\quad X&=0,\qquad \theta_s=\theta_f=\theta_c=0.
\end{align*}
Note that $\epsilon, \kappa, Bi, U_p, A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4$ are constants.

> I want to solve for $\theta_s,\;\theta_f,$ and $\theta_c.$

Comment: Just to clarify: the pde's are linear in the dependent variables $\theta_s, \theta_c,$ and $\theta_f$.

Comment: Actually Eq. 1 is nonlinear PDE and the rest are the linear PDE @AdrianKeister

Comment: All three pde's are linear in the $\theta$ variables. Even your boundary conditions are linear in the $\theta$ variables. Unless you are reporting one of the equations incorrectly, they are all linear. If you think the first equation is nonlinear, please point out the nonlinearity.

Comment: Because Eq. 1 involves the Y^2 term, that's why I consider it nonlinear PDE. If it is linear, as you said, so which method is suitable to solve this PDE

Comment: Usually the linearity of a DE is determined by whether its *dependent* variables are linear. In this case, that is your $\theta_s, \theta_f, \theta_c.$ Because $Y$ is an *independent* variable, how it shows up in the DE has nothing to do with linearity. Personally, I would hand this system of pde's over to a computer to do numerically. I doubt you could find an analytical solution. One thing I would point out: the first equation alone has $\theta_c$ in it, and it doesn't have $\theta_s$ or $\theta_f$. That is, $\theta_c$ is de-coupled in the actual equations. It's coupled in the BC's, though.

Comment: Yes, you are right it's a linear equation. Actually, I want to do it analytically, but I am stuck in the first equation. I am not familiar with the numerical solution and all equations are right along with their BC's. Yes in Eq. 1 I have only θc it does not depend on θs and θf.

Comment: You could try a Laplace Transform in $X,$ since it's only first-order in $X.$

Comment: Please, can you help me to solve it numerically? @AdrianKeister

Comment: Which of your constants are biggest in magnitude?

Comment: Constants Bi and K (kappa) are higher.

Comment: Can you give me order-of-magnitude estimates for each of your constants? I'm trying to figure out if you have stiff pde's or not.

Comment: Please note the following values, ϵ=0.8,κ=1,Bi=1,Up= -0.001, A1= -0.10838, A2= 0.188704, A3= -0.08038, A4= 0.847246

Comment: Ok, that doesn't look stiff to me. Your pde's are parabolic, I should think - that may not be significant. I would throw this to a finite-element solver, particularly if you have a non-trivial geometry. You have one unusual characteristic of your BC's: $Y$ has conditions at three points. That may or not be possible to achieve. You might have to combine finite-elements with some sort of shooting method to get all three conditions satisfied.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian Keister for your analysis. Can you show me some steps? because I am new in numerical analysis. It will help me to solve.

Comment: I'm afraid I know next to nothing about FEM other than the very basics. There are tons of software packages out there, though, that can probably do what you want here. Though, as I said, the three conditions on different values of $Y$ is a curveball.

Comment: FFT is usually short for Fast Fourier Transform and not Finite Fourier Transform.

Comment: Yes there is no nonlinear term here. The $-\frac{A_4}{\epsilon(Y^2A_1+YA_2+A_3)}$ is a function in variable $Y$. It would be non linear if any of the functions you are solving for are concatenated with a non-linear function. For example $\sin(\theta _c), (\theta _c)^2$ or stuff like that.